# To many errors in installing Anbox on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, lts, anbox

Is there just any way i can use anbox on 20.04?
When I run `sudo apt-get install dkms` i get this error

```
sudo apt install dkms

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
dkms is already the newest version (2.8.1-5ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up anbox-modules-dkms (13) ...
Removing old anbox-1 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 1
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new anbox-1 DKMS files...
Building for 5.11.0-27-generic
Building initial module for 5.11.0-27-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/anbox-modules-d
kms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.11.0-27-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/anbox/1/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package anbox-modules-dkms (--configure):
 installed anbox-modules-dkms package post-installation script subprocess return
ed error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 anbox-modules-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

when i run `sudo apt install linux-headers-generic anbox-modules-dkms` , it give me this error

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-generic anbox-modules-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package anbox-modules-dkms is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'anbox-modules-dkms' has no installation candidate
```

And when i run `ls -1 /dev/{ashmem,binder}`
It gives me this--

```
ls -1 /dev/{ashmem,binder}
ls: cannot access '/dev/binder': No such file or directory
**/dev/ashmem**
```

And whin i run this--`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:morphis/anbox-support`
it give me this--

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

and by running `snap info anbox`
it gives this--

```
snap info anbox
name:      anbox
summary:   Android in a Box
publisher: Simon Fels (morphis)
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/anbox
contact:   https://anbox.io
license:   unset
description: |
  Runtime for Android applications which runs a full Android system
  in a container using Linux namespaces (user, ipc, net, mount) to
  separate the Android system fully from the host.
  
  You can find further details in our documentation at
  https://github.com/anbox/anbox/blob/master/README.md
commands:
  - anbox
  - anbox.android-settings
  - anbox.appmgr
  - anbox.collect-bug-info
  - anbox.shell
services:
  anbox.container-manager: simple, enabled, active
snap-id:      Nr9K6UJaIOD8wHpDEQl16nabFFt9LLEQ
tracking:     latest/beta
refresh-date: today at 15:58 IST
channels:
  latest/stable:    --                                   
  latest/candidate: --                                   
  latest/beta:      4-56c25f1     2020-01-02 (186) 391MB devmode
  latest/edge:      4+gitrad377ff 2021-05-27 (213) 405MB devmode
installed:          4-56c25f1                (186) 391MB devmode
```

Comment: Read your output: You did successfully install Anbox. You installed the snap. Stop mucking with all those deb commands, uninstall whatever debs you installed, and remove that PPA. Looks like you failed to modprobe /dev/binder. You did not need to install any kernel packages -- Anbox kernel modules have been included since 19.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, it is not needed any more to install the kernels [starting from Ubuntu 19.04](https://docs.anbox.io/userguide/install_kernel_modules.html), thus no PPA are required too.

It is just needed to install `ashmem` and `binder` using

```
sudo modprobe ashmem_linux
sudo modprobe binder_linux
```

To verify a successful installation, use `lsmod | grep -e ashmem_linux -e binder_linux`

Make sure not to misspell 'ashmem'

It is now possible to install the latest dev beta version of `anbox` using snap

```
snap install anbox --beta --devmode
```

but on the `anbox` git page [it is suggested](https://github.com/anbox/anbox/issues/1653) to update to the edge version

```
snap refresh --devmode --edge anbox
```

For the first dry start, I found useful preloading some stuff while lunching the app

```
anbox launch --package=org.anbox.appmgr --component=org.anbox.appmgr.AppViewActivity
```

You can follow [this procedure](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/10/anbox-run-android-apps-ubuntu/) to install the Google Play Store if it is in your interest.